# "Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, office365, adal

```
try
{
    ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential("***********","**************");
    UserIdentifier userIdentifier = new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId);

    DiscoveryClient discClient = new DiscoveryClient(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceEndpointUri,
        async () =>
        {
            var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceResourceId,
                                                                       clientCredential, userIdentifier);

            return authResult.AccessToken;
        });

    var dcr = await discClient.DiscoverCapabilityAsync(capabilityName);

    return new OutlookServicesClient(dcr.ServiceEndpointUri,
        async () =>
        {
            var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(dcr.ServiceResourceId, clientCredential, userIdentifier);
            return authResult.AccessToken;
        });
}
catch (AdalException exception)
{
    //Handle token acquisition failure
    if (exception.ErrorCode == AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently)
    {
        authContext.TokenCache.Clear();
        throw exception;
    }
    return null;
}
```

giving error "Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken"

Comment: Have you seen this similiar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632507/failed-to-acquire-token-silently-call-method-acquiretoken

Comment: Yes, I have checked and i am not having that mistake.

Comment: guys will you suggest something else?

Comment: > I stumpled on your question due to a review process. However, my knowledge regarding the subject is limited. But if you give it a moment someone could stumple on it. I also added the C#-tag for you, which may attract more attention.

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure the app is registered under **Office 365 tenant AD**, else you will fail to discover and consume the Office 365 services.

Step#1 Download the sample project [AspNetMvc-with-O365.zip](https://github.com/dream-365/OfficeDev-Samples/releases/download/1.0/AspNetMvc-with-O365.zip).

Step#2 Register an app under Office 365 tenant AD, declare the Office 365 Exchange Online > Read user mail permission and set the REPLY URL as "http://localhost:2659/".
[image]

Step#3 In the web.config file, copy the ClientId, TenantId and Client Secret from Azure AD portal.

[image]

Step#4 Run the project in Visual Studio and log in with Azure AD account

The expected result should be as following:

[image]

You can also click the "Clear the cache database" button if you have acquire token issues.